# Under slab leak

Tags: water, leak

I had a pipe break under my slab. It sounded like rushing water, a river almost.   We found the leak an it only went to a outside faucet.  So we capped off the pipe.   Is that enough?

Comment: It should be if you do not want to use the outside faucet.  I assume by capped you mean you cut the pipe before the leak, and put a cap on it to stop the water flowing.

Comment: How did you cap off a leak under your slab? Did you turn off the valve supplying water to the outside faucet?

Answer (score 1):

If your water meter is no longer spinning crazily (or at all) when every faucet in the house is turned off, then yes, your fix is sufficient.

If you want a hose bib for water outside, then you'll need to run a completely new line or replace the cap with new, unbroken pipe.